# display message alert after email pop up window is dismissed in app

Tags: swift, xcode9, uialertaction

I would like to inmediately AFTER I tap send or cancel my email pop up window , to display a alert controller showing if my mail was sent or not, I have managed to show the alert controller just BEFORE sending the message but not AFTER...:

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {


    switch result {
    case .cancelled:

        let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Cancelled", message: "Send Email has been cancelled", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) in
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        controller.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    case .sent:



        let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Sent", message: "Message Sent Successfully", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) in
           controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))



    default:
        break;
    }
```

this is what I have tried

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to use a controller which is a popup plus it's going to be dismissed , You can try

```
 UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: you mean like replacing the last line of my code with this new line?

Comment: any line that has controller.present

Comment: if I try that method it will not dismiss my email window :/